# How do I map another column into Hibernate bean?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have an object that is mapped to Hibernate using a hbm.xml file. The BEAN/object for the table includes an extra field, with appropriate getter/setters. I want to do something like:

```
SELECT T.*, 'XYZ' as otherData FROM table T
```

and have all the data mapped into the BEAN, including the value of the fake/additional column - 'otherData.'

This should be simple and maybe I'm missing something easy, but I cant get it to work. I've tried using

```
createSQLquery() with addEntity(), addScalar(), setResultTransformer()
```

and

```
createCriteria() with a projectionList() and setResultTransformer()
```

and whatever else I can think of and nothing gives the desired results. I dont want a generic list of Objects that I have to parse through to build my objects, and I don't want to have to specify every column of the table while building this query.

Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using a formula for the property. You can fill this with any SQL query data. Consider for example an order - order line relation where you want to fill a property of the order with the number of order lines, like:

```
public class Order {
  private String orderNumber;
  private int lineCount;
```

...
}

then the mapping would be:

```
<class name="Order" ....>
  ...
  <property name="lineCount"
    formula="(select COUNT(*) from ORDER_LINE l where l.ORDER_NUMBER = ORDER_NUMBER)"/>
  ...
</class>
```

Comment: Interesting, I may try this. Although I'm a little reluctant to have SQL in mapping files. I was hoping for something that would 'extend' the bean/mapping to include the other data. Thanks for the answer.